# Ruby Filename error?

Tags: ruby, scripting, duplicates, md5, invalid-argument

I forked this gist from https://gist.github.com/mattdipasquale/571405

I am getting the following error:

```
deDUPER.rb:14:in `read': Invalid argument - /Volumes/Drobo #1 2009-2012/AMNH Video/2012/2012-01-17 Creatures of Light/Capture Scratch/Art 3:9/Capture Scratch/2012-03-09_microraptor livestream/A Cam_Microraptor livestream.mov (Errno::EINVAL)
    from deDUPER.rb:14:in `block in <main>'
    from deDUPER.rb:10:in `each'
    from deDUPER.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I think it is caused from illegal characters in the file or folder names, but i'm not sure. I don't want to change the file or folder names because they are linked to old Final Cut Pro project files that rely on referenced filepaths to keep the project intact. Does anyone have experience with this? Is there a way I can get this script to work without having to change the file or folder names?

```
# Define the unique method that removes duplicates
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'digest/md5'

library_path = ARGV[0]

hash = {}

Dir.glob(library_path + "/**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).each do |filename|
  next if File.directory?(filename)
  puts 'Checking ' + filename

  key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(IO.read(filename)).to_sym
  if hash.has_key? key
    # puts "same file #{filename}"
    hash[key].push filename
  else
    hash[key] = [filename]
  end
end

hash.each_value do |filename_array|
  if filename_array.length > 1
    puts "=== Identical Files ===\n"
    filename_array.each { |filename| puts '  '+filename }
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the output of this line "puts 'Checking ' + filename"? from what I can tell, ruby is pretty tolerant of special characters, if it can be used in a filename, ruby usually plays well with it. What OS are you using?

Comment: Is it by any chance the longest filespec encountered up to that point?  I'm wondering if some code enforces a maximum less than its size even though other code and the filesystem permits that size.

Comment: Have you tried other filenames that work? You'll have to narrow down this problem, perhaps through trial and error.

Comment: @Jeff Price, I'm on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.5. The script processed all files up until it printed "/Volumes/Drobo #1 2009-2012/AMNH Video/2012/2012-01-17 Creatures of Light/Capture Scratch/Art 3:9/Capture Scratch/2012-03-09_microraptor livestream/A Cam_Microraptor livestream.mov"

Comment: @tadman yes, other filenames worked up until this point.

Comment: @KeithBennett is there a way I can check on the limitations of the filespec?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the error is being thrown by IO.read while trying to read the '.mov' file, which probably is too large in size. This is a limitation of IO.read.  Even if you split such big files and read in chunks, it'll kill the purpose of this script as it will then be identifying duplication of chunked files, and not the original massive file. The other option would be to ignore any files > max single read size limit for IO.read (which I think varies based on the platform)

Comment: I just googled "mac file name size maximum" and found that the filespec can be up to 256 characters.  As an experiment, I would recommend taking your offending filespec, change all slashes to underscores, and for each special character, do this: 1) change occurrences of that character to an underscore, `File.write(new_filespec, 'foo'); IO.read(new_filespec)` to see if one of those substitutions results in a successful read.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I'll give them a shot.